# jQuery Validate Plugin: Email validation only happens on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

SOLVED: I inspected my version of jquery-validate.js and found that it didn't implement the onkeyup handler in the first place. I am using 1.12 Opre. I don't know why it didn't include that handler because from what I see on github that functionality for onkeyup was available in 2013. Maybe I got a bad fork from somewhere. So, all I did was update to 1.14 and everything is working as expected.

UPDATE: After more research I'm realizing the problem is more about validation not being done on "onkeyup", which the jQuery Validate Plugin is supposed to do by default.

Maybe it's the way I'm using the jQuery validate plugin but if I enter an invalid email I show a red alert area below the input:

```
var validationPluginDefaults = {
ignore: [],
errorElement: 'p', //default input error message container <p>
errorClass: 'text-error', // default input error message class
focusInvalid: true, //focus on the first invalid field
messages: {},
invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit 

},
highlight: function (el) { // hightlight error inputs
    //jQuery(el).closest('.control-group').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
},
success: function (err, el) {
    jQuery(el).next(".text-error").hide();
    jQuery(el).next(".text-error").remove();


},
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
},
onfocusin: function () {},
onfocusout: function () {}
```

};

When I correct the email and hit my submit button directly (without triggering an onblur event) the previous error field gets removed and the form then jumps...making me miss hitting it correctly.

Here's my validator rules:

```
var validator = jQuery.extend(validationPluginDefaults,{
    rules: {
        loginName: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
        },
        firstName: {
            minlength: 2,
            onlyAlphaAndHyphen: true,
            required: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            equalTo: "#loginName",
        }
    }
});
```

And here's how I trigger it inside my function:

```
$("#updateUserForm").validate(validator);


    if ($("#updateUserForm").valid()){
```

Now I know you don't normally call .validate() right before .valid() and that you should be calling it on page load. But I inherited someone's bad code and this is what I've got so far. Regardless, I tried it the other way and I still saw the error.

Can't this email validation be done during the text change event so I don't have to exit the field?

Comment: I inspected the jquery-validate.js file and I found that I have version 1.12 from 2013 and it didn't have an "onkeyup" handler defined. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to achieve this by using the onChange event?

`$("#updateUserForm").on('change', 'input', function() {
   $(this).validate(validator);
});`

Comment: I didn't try that but it's definitely an interesting way to go about it; thanks for your input. I think I'd rather just update to the latest version of the plugin and get the built-in functionality working rather than support an incomplete plugin which is what I appear to have now.

Comment: If any other issues, feel free to ask again. But keep in mind always to get updated versions of jquery libs, deprecated versions are just like a timebomb